# Goats have evolved to become bipedal. What do they do with their hands?

Tags: biology, evolution

I am working on a race for my fantasy setting that is a bipedal mix between a yeti and a goat. Covered in fur, strong powerful legs for jumping far, accustomed to cold, mountainous terrain.

My initial thought was some sort of retractable claws that could dig into stone to help secure a perch while climbing.

What would be a reasonable evolution for them to have on their hands? I was thinking something that allows for use of tools, so opposable thumbs are required, but aside from that, I'd like some input. I don't have any other constraints.

Comment: This question has been repeated many times on the site before, I would tag it as a duplicate but there are too many to tag, search the words in your question or ungulate questions. Good luck.

Comment: Most of what I was searching turned up the feasibility, not so much specifics for hands. Thanks though.

Comment: They do whatever you want them to do, it's your story after all. If you're looking for actual motives, look at our evolution from bipedal to quadrupedal and then see if the goats would have similar pressures. The Ibex can already climb on a nearly 90 degree angle as they are, so I see no reason for an ibex-like animal to suddenly become bipedal or to actually require the ability to grasp if their environment doesn't induce pressures for developing said trait. If you really need a reason for them to exist Ike they do: they were made by mages, which means you choose the purpose.

Comment: It would need a complete revamp tbh but mostly the muscular structure and joint dexterity of their forelimbs, you could have the hooves soften into camel like feet with extended toes and much more mass needs to be added as well mobility of their joints.

Comment: What to use their newfound hands for? Anything! They can use them to groom their goatees, if they like.

Comment: You are basically asking anatomically correct Arimaspi. By the way, I was talking about the Arimaspi from MLP.

Answer (score 3):

**Who needs claws?  Goat toes rule!**

Dont mess up the goat toes!  Goat toes are already unsurpassed for climbing.  Mountain goats are the best mountain climbers there are.

https://www.core77.com/posts/18851/biomimetic-designers-take-note-goat-hooves-confer-ninja-like-climbing-abilities-18851#

[image: goat hoof]

> Unlike horses, goats have hooves comprised of two split toes. The
> outer part of each toe, which is shaped like a parabola when seen from
> below and is labeled "Wall" in the diagram below, is hard; the part
> marked "Sole" on the diagram is soft and rubbery.
>
> The parabolic shape of the hoof wall adds strength, while the cushy
> sole provides traction on sloped surfaces and can deform inwards to
> absorb irregularities in the terrain. **And because the toes can operate
> independently**, the goat can use just one to gain purchase on extremely
> narrow surfaces, or splay the toes to gain more contact area.

Emphasis mine because that is what you are going to alter, just a little.  Your goatyetis with prehensile front limbs have toes that are even more mobile than their purely goat ancestors.  The toes can pivot and pinch an object in between them.  It would not surprise me to learn that they already can do that to some degree, but goats have so far not been inclined to use that skill with a paintbrush or cigar.

Your goat yetis will still drop to all four when there is serious climbing to be done and the front limbs are still good for that.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution happens when small changes that give an advantage accrue over generations. Human-like grabbing hands evolved as an aid to arboreal movement. If you want your goat men to develop hands that are good for manipulating objects, it might be a good idea to have some kind of tree that grows all across the mountain ranges that the goats like to hang out in.

Two quick Google searches, one for "trees that are good for climbing" and the other for "trees that grow in mountains" both yielded maple trees, if you want to use a real-world tree type. If your setting is based on a specific region of the real world, you could look for trees that grow near there.

Comment: If there are simians in the ecology, they may cause plants to develop more arcane shells as a defense, which may encourage your goats in a similar direction. Likewise, direct warfare with simians may drive more coordination as they try to imitate tool use, and most successful of those survive.

Comment: Just remember the key insights of modern evolution theory: a) complexity is always universal and b) causes drive evolution, not outcomes (I.e. we didn’t become intelligent in order to become tool users... tool use was a side effect).

Answer (score 0):

Therizinosaurs were herbivorous theropod dinosaurs that used their sickle-like claws to pull down fruit and foliage to eat.  If a grazing animal developed bipedalism, it could use its forelimbs the same way.